# Problems with CORS Response to preflight in dotnet 8

Tags: reactjs, .net, cors, .net-8.0

I am facing this issue:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5001/api/Register/CheckNationalCode' from origin 'http://192.168.1.128:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

On backend side I tried this way and didn't worked:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
    {
        builder .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
               .AllowCredentials(); // allow credentials
    });

});
```

and this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT");
    await next();
});
// Use CORS
app.UseCors("AllowAll");

app.Map("/", () => Results.Redirect("/api"));

app.MapEndpoints().UseCors("AllowAll");

app.Run();
```

Environment:

Dotnet Core 8
React 17

Comment: It's telling you the problem that your preflight is redirecting

Comment: No solution to your issue, but be aware that `SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)` in conjunction with `AllowCredentials()` is insecure.